# Why doesn't my ClickOnce application recognize there is an upgrade the first time I open the application after deploying a new version?

Tags: clickonce, upgrade

1. I deploy a new version of my ClickOnce application
2. I open my ClickOnce application on the test client machine
3. No upgrade is offered
4. I close my ClickOnce application and re-open it and now the upgrade is offered

Why do I have to open, close, and re-open in order to upgrade?

ClickOnce? More like click four times!

What's up with this?

Comment: This sounds really strange to me. After you deploy, ClickOnce creates a new version folder on the ClickOnce svr, like App_1_0_2 and until this is done and until the .xml file is configured your local shortcut won't recognize the new version.

Comment: All that is happening. All files are deployed to the correct server and are there when I initially open the application after deploying.

Comment: Can you accept [stuartd's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819623/why-doesnt-my-clickonce-application-recognize-there-is-an-upgrade-the-first-tim/4819762#4819762) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the xml of the **YourAppName.application** which will be deployed with the rest of the assemblies, etc, onto the deploy server.

Check the **minimumRequiredVersion="1.0.0.0"** and make sure that before you publish you get these properties properly set up (I assume you do).

Then, if you serve this app off of a web server, might wanna check if the server is not serving a cached copy **YourAppName.application** the first time you try running the app.

Good luck!

Comment: I do not have any minimum required version set in the deployment settings of the project. Should I have one? I believe it was disabled by default.

Comment: Enable it, and set the Major,Minor,Build,Revision numbers to the same that you are publishing. Give it a try!

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like your project is set to check for updates 'After the application starts' rather than 'Before your application starts' - check the settings on the Publish tab of the project properties, and click the 'Updates' button.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

> **Checking for Updates After Application Startup** 
>   By using this strategy, the
>   application will attempt to locate and
>   read the deployment manifest file in
>   the background while the application
>   is running. If an update is available,
>   the next time that the user runs the
>   application, he will be prompted to
>   download and install the update.

Comment: Interesting ... why would anyone ever want to wait until after application startup?

Comment: Good idea, but I just looked at the settings and it's set to do it right away ... not after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, remember every time update must change new version.
[image]